# SQL Query (Find Range On Dates Stored as Strings)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I am currently working with a database which the dates are stored as strings in the (DD/MM/YYYY) format.

I am currently attempting to find a range of dates i.e. (15/07/2017 - 26/07/2017) which will then populate a weekly list.

The issue I am having it because these values are stored as strings within SQL I am unable to select a range unless I specify the values.

I am wondering are there any SQL Wizards out there who can help me.

Thanks, 
Joe

Comment: Store dates in the correct format. Then get back to us

Comment: I didn't make the database its preexisting. Poor design i know but whats the need.

Comment: If someone gave you a bicycle with a square wheel, would you ride it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hello Everyone I amended my answer as the previous one was incorrect and unhelpful to other users. In short I had to change the Dates to be stored as Dates correctly within SQL. In short there was no short cut unfortunately.

This is a the SQL Query which i used (No SQL Injection Protected), I hope this is helpful

```
"SELECT * FROM placement WHERE ('" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' 
between StartDate and EndDate OR '" + EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' 
between StartDate and EndDate or StartDate = '" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy-
MM-dd") + "' or EndDate = '" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' or 
StartDate = '" + EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' or EndDate = '" + 
EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "') AND YearGroup = '" + 
User.IntakeYear.ToString() + "' AND Cohort = '" + User.Cohort.ToString() + 
"';";
```

Thanks For Your Feedback.

Comment: That won't quite work since the dates are stored as strings. You'll need to convert to date to use the between function. See @scaisEdge answer for an example. It's going to be tough on your server. You really should either convert to a timestamp column type, or add columns in timestamp and copy to the data with conversion.

Comment: This will not work.  These are *not* dates, they are strings, and they will use the same comparison methods that a string will.  As an example - using your code, `11/04/2016` is `BETWEEN` `10/07/2017` and `16/07/2017` because it's sorting *as a string*.  You'll need to use a method like in @scaisEdge's answer.

Comment: Thanks Sloan I Will Look Into It. Its very annoying they are stored as strings i know.

Answer (score 3):

you can use between and str_to_date eg:

```
 select * 
 from my_table 
 where str_to_date(my__date_column, '%d/%m/%Y')
     between str_to_date('15/07/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') 
      and str_to_date('26/07/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Brilliant Thanks a lot :)